# I did not get data from the api. I need fetch data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, getserversideprops

```
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from 'next';
import Image from 'next/image';
import React from 'react';
import photo from '../../assets/photo.jpg';

type Products = {
    data?: {
      id: number;
      title: string;
      body: string;
    }[];
  };
  
  const defaultProducts: Products = {
    data: [],
  };

const ExploreProducts: NextPage<Products> = ({ data = defaultProducts.data }) => {
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-12 gap-5'>
        {data?.map(product => (
          <div className="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-xl" key={product.id}>
            <figure className="px-10 pt-10">
              <Image src={photo} alt="Shoes" className="rounded-xl" />
            </figure>
            <div className="card-body items-center text-center">
              <h2 className="card-title">{product.title}</h2>
              <p>{product.body}</p>
              <div className="card-actions">
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Products> = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data); // Verify that data is being fetched correctly
    return {
      props: {
        data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      props: {
        data: [],
      },
    };
  }
};

export default ExploreProducts;
```

This is my whole component I am trying fetch data from jsonplaceholder but data is undefined or array is 0. I can't understand what is problem in this code. I am try to fetch data from the api. but I got undefined data or array is 0. I do not understand what is happening. What problem in my code. Please review this code and tell me what is problem in this code.

I am expecting data from the API want to show in UI.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, no issues with your code, just work fine.
I tried in GitHub codespaces just works fine. refer to the below SS.

[image: working code screenshot]

Comment: Additionally, you can put the check in your component while rendering `data && data.length > 0` in the mao=p.

Comment: but still, I am not getting the data. In the console showing undefined.

Comment: When I useEffect data coming from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a state to manage the data you're getting and set the state from the fetch. Afterwards, you can pass it down as props to the children components. I prefer to use axios to fetch data.

```
const [defaultProperties, setDefaultProperties] = useState([]);

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Products> = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    const data = await response.json();
    setDefaultProperties(data)
    console.log(data); // Verify that data is being fetched correctly
    return {
      props: {
        data: DefaultProperties,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      props: {
        data: [],
      },
    };
  }
};
```